# can I have a directed cyclic graph with just two vertexes?

Tags: graph, nodes, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

Is this a legal cyclic directed graph? It has only two nodes.

```
 A  --------->   B
      <--------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have directed cycles between two nodes, its completely valid.
even cycles from Node A to Node A is valid (in case of undirected)